# Magento Observer generate errors and Magento areas confusing

Tags: magento, observers

I've made `controller_front_init_routers` event observer, which retrieves data from a `REST` service to construct a menu. 
All was ok until I discovered that the observer generates errors in the backend (no way to save  products for example) and also in the rest services.
I am struggling for any conclusions, So I raised some interrogations.

1. I tried to make a condition in order to trigger my Observer
   methods in case we are in frontend only. But Magento considers that we are
   always in frontend area.

> (var_dump(Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin()) return always false
>       and the same with var_dump(Mage::getDesign()->getArea() ==
>       'adminhtml'))

```
Can anyone explain what's happened ?
```

2. Also one solution is to place the event observer in frontend
   area in the `config.xml` and to load it with 
   `Mage::app()->loadArea($this->getLayout()->getArea());` but where  should I
   place this piece of code ? in  a new observer ?  Is that the most
   appropriate process ?
3. Is it a way to listen once an event then to pause the listener?
   (once my menu is registered, I don't need to listen to the event any more)
4. Is the use of `controller_front_init_routers` event the best choice ?
5. Who has ever seen that kind of problem ?

I work on Magento ver. 1.12.0.2

Here the config.xml

```
<globals>
....
<events>
<controller_front_init_routers>
<observers>
  <connector_services_observer>
    <type>singleton</type>
    <class>Connector_Services_Model_Observer</class>
      <method>getEvent</method>
       </connector_services_observer>
  </observers>
</controller_front_init_routers>        
</events>
</globals>
```

Here the function getEvent in my model observer

```
public function getEvent($observer){

    //model which do post or get requests and return xml and menu
    $_getRest = Mage::getModel('connector_services/RestRequest');
    //the paths
    $_menu_url = Mage::getStoreConfig('connector_service_section/connector_service_url/service_menu_url');
    //put a store config
    $path_nlist = 'veritas-pages-list.xml';

    $_isAdmin = Mage::helper('connector_services');

    $currentUrl=Mage::helper("core/url")->getCurrentUrl();
    //the way I found to trigger methods only in frontend
            //that's not very beautiful I know
        $admin = preg_match("#/admin/#",$currentUrl);
        $api =  preg_match("#/api/#",$currentUrl);
    //
    if ( !$admin && ! $api ){


            $_menuXml = $_getRest->postRequest($_menu_url);

            if( $_menuXml )
            { 
                $_menu = $_getRest->makeMenu($_menuXml);
                Mage::register('menu',$_menu); 
            }  


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to pass a querystring to the rest service, similar to how you'd just type it out in the address bar. Magento will forward it on to the observer, and you can use it as a flag.

Add something like the following to your code:

```
const USE_FRONTEND = 'usefront';

public function getEvent($observer){
    this->request = $observer->getEvent()->getData('front')->getRequest();

    // If the constant is in the query string 
    if ($this->request->{self::USE_FRONTEND}) {
        // Do code related to this request
        die('Frontend flag detected');
    }

}
```

Call to your site like this and pass the querystring

http://www.yourmagentosite.com/?usefront=true

I am not extremely familiar with Magento's new REST api, but I know it works in the browser. Maybe this explanation can help you out.

Comment: Was this helpful in any way?